# Getting SIGSEGV (segmentation error) for the given problem. (Finding LCA of a generic tree)

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, lowest-common-ancestor

So, I was trying to solve the below problem using the most basic method i.e. storing the paths and finding LCA.
My code is working fine on VSCode and giving the right output. But when submitting on [SPOJ](https://www.spoj.com/), it gives runtime error (SIGSEGV).

**Problem Link**: https://www.spoj.com/problems/LCA/

**Problem Description**:

A tree is an undirected graph in which any two vertices are connected by exactly one simple path. In other words, any connected graph without cycles is a tree. - Wikipedia

The lowest common ancestor (LCA) is a concept in graph theory and computer science. Let T be a rooted tree with N nodes. The lowest common ancestor is defined between two nodes v and w as the lowest node in T that has both v and w as descendants (where we allow a node to be a descendant of itself). - Wikipedia

Your task in this problem is to find the LCA of any two given nodes v and w in a given tree T.

**Sample Input:**

```
1
7
3 2 3 4
0
3 5 6 7
0
0
0
0
2
5 7
2 7
```

**Sample Output:**

```
Case 1:
3
1
```

**My Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

vector<vector<int>> edges;

bool storepath(int s, int d,  vector<int>& path, vector<bool>& visited) {
   if(s == d)
   {
       path.push_back(d);
       return true;
   }

   else if(edges[s].size() == 1) {
       if(s != d)
       {
           for(int i = 0; i < path.size(); i++)
               if(path[i] == s) {
                   path.erase(path.begin() + i);
               }
       }
       return false;
   }

   visited[s] = true;
   path.push_back(s);
   for(auto e: edges[s])
   {
       if(visited[e] == false)
       { 
           bool ans = storepath(e, d, path, visited);
           if(ans)
               break;
       }
   }
}

int LCA(int a, int b)
{
   if(a == b)
       return a;
   vector<int> path1, path2;

   vector<bool> visited(edges.size(), false);
   storepath(1, a, path1, visited);
   visited.assign(edges.size(), false);
   storepath(1, b, path2, visited);

   int n = path1.size();       
   int m = path2.size();

   int i = 0,j = 0;
   while(i < n && j < m && path1[i] == path2[j]) {
       i++;
       j++;
   }

   return path1[i-1];
}

int main() {
   ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
   cin.tie(0);cout.tie(0);

   int t;
   cin >> t;
   int Case = 1;
   while(t--)
   {
       int n;
       cin >> n;
       
       edges.resize(n+1);
       for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
       {
           int size, val;
           cin >> size;
           while(size--)
           {
               cin >> val;
               edges[i].push_back(val);
               edges[val].push_back(i);
           }
       }


       int q;
       cin >> q;
       cout << "Case "<< Case << ":" << endl;
       while(q--)
       {
           int a, b;
           cin >> a >> b;
           cout << LCA(a, b) << endl;
       }
       Case++;
       edges.clear(); //added after igor's comment (forgot to add before but used while submitting)
   }

   return 0;   
}
```

I think I'm not accessing any out of scope element so SIGSEGV should not occur. 
Please tell me how can I fix and improve my code.

Comment: `edges.resize` doesn't clear any existing data from the vector if the new size is larger than the previous one. So when processing next test case you may still have previous graph in that vector. So the graph might no longer be a tree. Also all these edges may contribute to excessive memory use which may result in the runtime error you're receiving. Use `edges.clear()` instead before resizing.

Comment: @Igor Yes, I did that while submitting (forgot to change here, I'll update right now)  but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some bugs are easy to find, when you know how to find them. The tools every programmer should know about are `valgrind` and `-fsanitize`. Remember to always compile with warnings enabled and fix them. Compiling your code with:

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra -fsanitize=undefined 1.cpp && ./a.out </tmp/2
```

results in a helpful warning:

```
1.cpp:38:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
   38 | }
      | ^
```

and a runtime error:

```
1.cpp:9:6: runtime error: execution reached the end of a value-returning function without returning a value
```

Your `storepath` doesn't return value.

Comment: Oh god! Thanks a lot for pointing this out!! I'm very sad to admit that it's the second time I'm making this mistake. Will surely take care of it from now on. Thanks again! Also, I want to ask where can I learn these debugging skills/commands?

Comment: `where can I learn these debugging skills/commands?` well... to be honest, experience :/ just research, I mostly learnt on stackoverflow

Comment: Great! I definitely will.